# PHP script keeps sending blank emails

Tags: php, validation, email

For some reason the php script does not end when emptiness condition is met and keeps sending blank email when the user press submit button. Even though the error messages are displayed I receive a blank email in my inbox. Please help.

````
<?php
$name_error=$email_error=$message_error=$send_error="";
$name=$email=$message=$success="";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  

        //check name
  if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    $name_error= 'Enter name<br />';  
  } else {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $name)){
      $name_error= 'Letters and spaces only';      
    }         
  }
       //check email
  if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    $email_error='Enter email<br />';    
  } else {
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $email_error='Enter a valid email';          
    }
  }
        //check message
  if(empty($_POST['message'])){
    $message_error= 'Enter message<br />';   
  } else {
    $message=test_input($_POST['message']);
  }
  
  if($name=='' or $email=='' or $message==''){
    $send_error='The message could not be sent.'; 
  }
  
    $to="contact@contact.com";
    $subject="Contact from website";
    $txt="From: ".$name.".\n\n".$message;
    $body="From: ".$email; 

  if(mail($to, $subject, $txt, $body)){
    $success='Message sent';
    $name=$email=$message=$success=""; 
  } else {
    $send_error='The message could not be sent.';        
  }

}

function test_input($data){
  $data=trim($data);
  $data=stripslashes($data);
  $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>
```
````

Comment: if(empty(trim($_POST['message']))){ add trim to get rid spaces and non prinables.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code - it would send the email no matter what.
The condition that I believe you've meant should "stop" the continuation of the script is:

```
  if($name=='' or $email=='' or $message==''){
    $send_error='The message could not be sent.'; 
  }
```

The script will continue to the following lines, rather the condition return true or false. and the rest of the code - is the code that sends the email.

```
    $to="contact@contact.com";
    $subject="Contact from website";
    $txt="From: ".$name.".\n\n".$message;
    $body="From: ".$email; 

  if(mail($to, $subject, $txt, $body)){
    $success='Message sent';
    $name=$email=$message=$success=""; 
  } else {
    $send_error='The message could not be sent.';        
  }
```

The solution would be to use `else` for the validation condition.

```
  if($name=='' or $email=='' or $message==''){
    $send_error='The message could not be sent.'; 
  } else {
    $to="contact@contact.com";
    $subject="Contact from website";
    $txt="From: ".$name.".\n\n".$message;
    $body="From: ".$email; 

    if(mail($to, $subject, $txt, $body)){
      $success='Message sent';
      $name=$email=$message=$success=""; 
    } else {
      $send_error='The message could not be sent.';        
    } 

  }
```

Comment: Great! IT works. Begginer's mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works for you now :) If my answer helped you please considering accepting it. Good luck